# Pass textbox value to JS function to convert to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a javascript function which is supposed to take in a value from a textbox, convert it to JSON and display the JSON in an alert. This is what I have and it's not working, can anyone see why?

```
console.log(document);
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

form.onsubmit = function (e) {

  // stop the regular form submission
  e.preventDefault();

   //Collect the data and convert to JSON
var mydata = JSON.stringify(inputbox.value);

   //Show me the JSON
    alert(mydata);

}
```

Here's my form-

```
<form id = "myForm">
<div class="col-lg-6">

    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id = "input" name = "inputbox" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn"> 
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id = "add" >Add</button>
      </span>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't assigned an element to `inputbox`.

Comment: In the form, it's the name of my textbox?

Comment: BTW, an input value is already a string. Any reason why you're stringifying it?

Comment: New to JSON, javascript- thought it needed to be done in order to convert to JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign an element to `inputbox`:

```
var inputbox = form.inputbox;
```

Also: your `add` button should be `type="submit"`.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/t4BFr/)